# Cannot create a New ColdFusion project in ColdFusion Builder 2

Tags: coldfusion-10, coldfusionbuilder

I am doing this as part of the linda.com course "Getting Started with ColdFusion 10"  I completed course once with no trouble, but going back to try going thru it again, I cannot create new projects.  Here is what I sent lynda.com.  They advised it could be weeks before they get to it.

I cannot add the travelAdv project following the directions in the video to add a new ColdFusion project.  I completed this course and wanted to go thru it again.  I deleted the files in c:\coldfusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\travelAdv.  Then I added them again from the download using the start files in chapter 1.  When I try to create it, I start with the Project Location of C:/ColdFusion/wwwroot.
I add the Project Name, travelAdv.  When I click the Next button, the message at the top of the pop-up window is
"Project with travelAdv already exists.  Select a different project name.  I changed the name to travelAdv2.  I set up the localhost as the server and the Sample URL is http://localhost:8500/travelAdv2/
Then I click finish.  No project appears in the Navigator.  It is totally empty.  Under the Project tab at the top, The open a project option is disabled.

I have tried several different project names off of wwwroot, but they never add the project to the navigator.  I searched the internet multiple times this past week and no one seems to have the same problem.  I must be missing something.   Any help would be appreciated.

Joe Bigler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to upgrade to ColdFusion Builder 2016.  The instructor of the course advised ColdFusion Builder was now too old and with too many issues to work on Windows 10.  I uninstalled the old version and installed the trial of ColdFusion 2016.  Everything seems to be working as expected so far.  I can use existing projects and create new ones.